# Gson - Convert form json (List inside List) to List<> Android

Tags: android, json, gson

Yesterday I managed on how to convert a json to a list<>, the json file was quite simple.

Now I have a son file which has a list inside List here is it :

<

here my code :

```
listq = new ArrayList<Survey>();

    try {
        result =    new RequestTask().execute("urveys/current?owner=ofc&user=yasser&category=-1").get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
      GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
       Gson gson = gsonb.create();
       listq = gson.fromJson(result,  Surveyentity.class).List;

       Toast.makeText(Questions.this, "result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

My class survey :

```
public class Survey {

String IdQuestion;
String Label;
List<Reponse> Reponses;
public String getIdQuestion() {
    return IdQuestion;
}
public void setIdQuestion(String idQuestion) {
    IdQuestion = idQuestion;
}
public String getLabel() {
    return Label;
}
public void setLabel(String label) {
    Label = label;
}
public List<Reponse> getReponses() {
    return Reponses;
}
public void setReponses(List<Reponse> reponses) {
    Reponses = reponses;
}
```

my class response :

```
public class Reponse {

String IdProposition;
String Label;
String Format;
String url;
String Points;
String Next;
String Comment;
String Selected;
public String getIdProposition() {
    return IdProposition;
}
public void setIdProposition(String idProposition) {
    IdProposition = idProposition;
}
.............
```

and my class survey entity :

```
public class Surveyentity {

 public List<Survey> List;
```

}

What's wrong with this ?

Comment: `List<Reponse> Reponses; ` should be `List<Reponse> List;`

Answer (score 0):

Update your Survey class

```
public class Survey {

String IdQuestion;
String Label;
List<Reponse> List; // it should be List not Responses
public String getIdQuestion() {
    return IdQuestion;
}
public void setIdQuestion(String idQuestion) {
    IdQuestion = idQuestion;
}
public String getLabel() {
    return Label;
}
public void setLabel(String label) {
    Label = label;
}
public List<Reponse> getReponses() {
    return Reponses;
}
public void setReponses(List<Reponse> reponses) {
    Reponses = reponses;
}
```

Comment: Why it should be List; I think it doesn't matter with the name

Comment: Gson uses reflection to map string in JSON. When deserializing, Gson is navigating the type tree of the object, which is being deserialized. This results in ignoring extra fields present in the JSON input.

Comment: Change String url; to String Url; in Reponse class

Comment: Please I updated the result of my json, can you please take a look, I think it's because the JSON result, so I have to change the code according to this result